# How to detect a specific WIFI network is connected by udev?

Tags: linux, wifi, nfs, udev

My system on laptop is Funtoo. I have a NAS at home and I'd like to mount some partitions automatically. Manually mount through NFS works already. Simply add lines to /etc/fstab is not a good solution, since when I goto work and connect to the WIFI at my office, the laptop boots very slow and got nothing.

So are there any way to detect the SSID when connecting a WIFI network and run the mount command if the SSID == my home network's SSID?

Or if there is other tools other than udev can archive this goal?

Comment: Do you use network manager? If so nmcli can be of help to you